# Why grafana doesn't show the data points?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

Grafana detects correctly the data from an influxDB (with a correct measurement). You can see at the image how the value of the field is 5, however, it is not well displayed at the plot.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Does your query actually return multiple datapoints? Check with the Query Inspector and post the results here

Comment: It is solved, the problem was how the influxdb was getting the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

My "no data points" error message occurred even when I could query influxdb and verify the data was there. A "show field keys" revealed that my data was in string form not a number. After changing the node-red code to save data as Numbers and dumping the old measurements in influxdb then my new data finally graphed.